# Remaining Stock Calculation in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to subtract the quantity inside products, with products added to an invoice. In order to figure out how many products are available in stock.

```
  SELECT
    w_prod.prod_article_pvt_uuid
    ,sum(coalesce(w_prod.quantity, 0) - coalesce(s_item.quantity, 0)) as available
  FROM products w_prod
  LEFT JOIN items s_item ON s_item.whse_prod_pvt_uuid = w_prod.whse_prod_pvt_uuid
  LEFT JOIN documents s_doc ON s_item.sale_doc_pvt_uuid = s_doc.sale_doc_pvt_uuid
  GROUP BY w_prod.prod_article_pvt_uuid
```

The expected output is as follows:

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------+
| prod_article_pvt_uuid                | available |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+
| 470fda1a-54ab-11ea-a21d-de2e50192004 | 5         |
| 9a59a5ba-5ad8-11ea-a21d-de2e50192004 | 10        |
| c2c98260-5482-11ea-a21d-de2e50192004 | 9         |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+
```

However the query above has trouble with `c2c98260-5482-11ea-a21d-de2e50192004` and returns `21` instead.

Take a look at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9ae0f4/1

**Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?**

---

Tables:

```
create table products
(
    whse_prod_pvt_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1() not null
            primary key,
    t timestamp with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    prod_article_pvt_uuid uuid not null,
    quantity numeric(16,6) default 1
);

create table documents
(
    sale_doc_pvt_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1() not null
            primary key,
    t timestamp with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
);

create table items
(
    sale_item_pvt_uuid uuid default uuid_generate_v1() not null
            primary key,
    t timestamp with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    sale_doc_pvt_uuid uuid not null,
    whse_prod_pvt_uuid uuid not null,
    quantity numeric(16,6) not null
);
```

Comment: When you join the `items` table, there are two rows that contain the uuid `821aa6b2-b0ea-11ea-9b8c-de2e50066011` thus the record from product with uuid `c2c98260-5482-11ea-a21d-de2e50192004` appears twice in the resultset. See the second query result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9ae0f4/43

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like so:

```
SELECT
    w_prod.prod_article_pvt_uuid
    ,(sum(w_prod.quantity) - s.quantity) as available
FROM warehousing.products w_prod
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        w_prod.prod_article_pvt_uuid
        ,sum(s_item.quantity) as quantity
    FROM warehousing.products w_prod
    LEFT JOIN sales.items s_item ON s_item.whse_prod_pvt_uuid = w_prod.whse_prod_pvt_uuid
    LEFT JOIN sales.documents s_doc ON s_item.sale_doc_pvt_uuid = s_doc.sale_doc_pvt_uuid    
    GROUP BY w_prod.prod_article_pvt_uuid
    ) s ON s.prod_article_pvt_uuid = w_prod.prod_article_pvt_uuid
GROUP BY w_prod.prod_article_pvt_uuid, s.quantity
```

It will be going in a materialized view.
If anyone has any optimization suggestions feel free to comment or post an answer.